# Azure App Service - how to configure port?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When I deploy example Spring Boot app to Azure App Service with Maven (just like in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-java?tabs=javase&pivots=platform-linux-development-environment-maven)), it works correctly regardles of *server.port* value in *application.properties* file. The App Service just "knows" what is the target port.

When I deploy other app, which is not based on Spring Boot and instead it is based on Tomcat Embedded and has port value hardcoded in its source code, the App Service does not work correctly. How can I "tell" the App Service what is the port that my app listens on?

Answer (score 1):

App Service always listens on port 80/443. You can map to the port your app listening on setting the WEBSITES_PORT application setting to your app port number.